# Single origin value for python matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple plot executed using matplotlib. My x and y axes start at 0,0 respectively. A matplotlib plot shows 2 zeros corresponding to the 2 axes. I want only one zero (somewhere in the middle of the start point, if possible).
How can this be done?

Here's what I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib Plot]

UPDATE:

I used @nostradamus' solution and it got rid of one of the zeros. I want the zero a little centred if possible.

I used:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower')) 
plt.gca().yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0].set_x(-0.05)
```

[image]

I want the reverse of this. I want the zero on the y axis to move down or the one from x axis left. So tried:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower')) 
plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0].set_x(-0.05)
```

It doesn't work. I think the bottom and left boundaries for the zeros are set to ensure they don't go beyond the area.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword is `prune`, which allows you to kill the `upper`, `lower` or `both` tick labels. Here is a working examples that gets rid of the 0 of the x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
plt.show()
```

The second part (to move the remaining zero to the corner) seems to be much more difficult. It seems that you can move single tick labels using

```
plt.gca().yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0].set_x(-0.05)
```

However, I was unable to figure out how to move it below the lower limit of the corresponding axis (i.e. `plt.gca().yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0].set_y(-0.05)` is doing nothing).

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know about `prune`. And yeah it seems to be really difficult editing the graphs created using pyplot